# thymeleaf-spring4:jar could not find artifact - gradle intelijj

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy, thymeleaf

I'm trying to build a simple application, using gradle, groovy, and spring-boot framework with this code:

```
@Grab("thymeleaf-spring4")

@Controller
class ViewBasedApp {
    def chapters = ["Quick Start With Groovy",
                    "Quick Start With Java",
                    "Debugging and Managing Your App",
                    "Data Access with Spring Boot",
                    "Securing Your App"]
    @RequestMapping("/")
    def home(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String n) {
        new ModelAndView("home")
                .addObject("name", n)
                .addObject("chapters", chapters)
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
group 'LoginApp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    //compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4") //first try
   // compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect") //first try
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.0.0.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4 //secound try
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring4', version: '3.0.0.RELEASE'
   // compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring4', version: '4.1.6.RELEASE' //third try
}
```

html file:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Learning Spring Boot - Chapter 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name}"></p>
<ol>
    <li th:each="chapter : ${chapters}" th:text="${chapter}"></li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

To launch my app I using spring boot CLI. When I have been using "spring run" in command prompt, I always have got the same error:
Could not find artifact :thymeleaf-spring4:jar: in local (file:/C:/Users/kubas/repository).

I have tried to add "thymeleaf-spring4.jar" - downloaded from maven page, to folder "repository" and nothing, always the same error.

Can anybody suggest on this?

Comment: This code works without @Grab annotation and only in STS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. I have used .html file and this is the way how I use this file in my Controller Class:

```
@RestController
class LoginServiceApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        def htmlContent = new File("F:\\APKA_W_SPRINGU\\Spring-apps-master\\AppWithLoginPage\\LoginService\\src\\main\\resources\\templates\\index.html").text

        htmlContent
    }
}
```

For the first question -  all I had have to do was a run main class in intelijj using  button run (Class must not contain @Grab annotation!), before I resolved this problem  I was using spring CLI  and that was a problem. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved issue by adding dependency from local Repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:3.0.9.RELEASE")
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect") //first try
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.6.RELEASE' //@EnableWebMvc @ComponentScan
}
```

Now thymeleaf is taken from C:\Users\kubas\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5

I had to change annotation in app.groovy to `@Grab("thymeleaf-spring5")`

but now I can't configure path to my templates file. My path to this file is:
`F:\gradle_login_aPP\src\main\resources\templates` ...

This is the error:

> Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/

I have tried add application.properties file in `\src\main\resources\`  but it doesn't work. I know it is possible to add default prefix, but I can't find information about file, where i need to add this. Any Suggestion, how to run this templates with gradle project?

Comment: I have tried to change classpath of template but nothig happened. I have added new Configuration class with  'templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");' and nothing